# Windows 2012 copy millions of small files

Tags: robocopy, incremental-backup, copy

I have to copy about ~12 millions of small files (less than ~100kb e/o) from one VM with W2012r2 to another VM with W2016, using a dedicated gigabit NIC.
I need to do an initial copy of all these files, then new files will be added to source and I need to sync or do an incremental copy of these new files to destination. Important note: files copied during initial copy will not be modified.

What is the best strategy to achieve this? Robocopy?

Thanks

Comment: I would zip or tar the files for the initial copy as it will be faster to copy one large file and extract at the target compared to copying millions of small files. Whether robocopy is efficient at syncing new files is another question.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, thanks for your reply. Zipping is not an option since I don't have enough space to do that. Thx.

Comment: zip them in batches?

Comment: for windows, yes robocopy is likely your best bet. you might want to consider (in addition to zipping), mounting the disk on the target VM temporarilly to take the network out of the equation, during the initial population.

Comment: Hi, thanks both. Finally, as @FrankThomas suggested, since the VMs reside in same datastore, I think I will attach a new VMDK to source VM, copy all data there, dettach disk and then attach it to destination VM for initial copy. Then, I will use robocopy to copy the delta.

Comment: Don't underestimate the throughput of a station wagon full of tape drives going down the highway at 55mph. Translated, this means that with certain sets of data, methods of transfer that may seem slower could end up being far faster in application